# Zend 1.12: Strip the path variable from url

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am generating urls in the view to get to an action on the specific entity via:

```php
   $link = $this->url(
        array(
            'action' => 'action',
            'controller' => 'controller',
            'module' => 'module',
            'id' => 'id'
        ),
        'default'
    );
   $this->backUrlAppend($link); // Adds `backUrl` GET parameter containing previous url.
```

Which generates action url `/controller/action/id/5`.

However when I decide to abort the action and generate a direct link back to search page (i.e. generated on action page) the `id` parameter is not stripped away and causes trouble latter on:

```php
   $link = $this->url(
        array(
            'action' => 'search',
            'controller' => 'controller',
            'module' => 'module'
        ),
        'default'
    );
   $this->backUrlAppend($link); // Adds `backUrl` GET parameter containing previous url.
```

Returns url: `/controller/search/id/5?backUrl=%2Fcontroller%2Faction%2Fid%2F5`

How can I force the view to not add the `id` parameter?

Comment: I am actually bypassing this in the controller (search action) by detecting the _id_  and redirecting to the base. However I am looking for a way how not to send the id in the first place.

Comment: Your problem probably starts with the way you `"abort the action and return back to search"`. It would be interesting to know what you mean by that and how you do it.

Comment: User simply clicks the button with URL generated by the second example to previous action. However the code (let say for `.../controller/action/id/1`) above generates `/controller/search/id/1` instead of '.../controller/search'. The problems are not immediate because the id is simply not processed but the redirecting URLs from search action (generated by the same way) are again being polluted by orphaned id.

Comment: NOTE: This question is outdated, and I no-longer have access to the affected code, and I'm not able to test any provided solution. :-\

PS: I've never figured out the answer myself.